# How to fix TypeScript error(ts:2740) like this

Tags: typescript

Sorry, I need a translator to use English. Please show the code in the answer. Thank you.

---

```js
// [message]: Type 'Promise<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'IDBDatabase': name, objectStoreNames, onabort, onclose, and 10 more.ts(2740)

const /*[message] here("IDB") -->*/ IDB: IDBDatabase | null = (async () => {
    return (await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = indexedDB.open("idb")
        request.onerror = (event) => {
            resolve(null)
        }
        request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
            resolve(null)
        }
        request.onsuccess = (event) => {
            resolve(request.result as IDBDatabase)
        }
        request.onblocked = () => {
            resolve(null)
        }
    }))
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using async functions incorrectly.
Your async function returns a `Promise<IDBDatabase | null>`, so you cannot assign it to `IDBDatabase | null`

You have 2 options to execute code when the promise resolves

- await in an async function
- use `then` on promise to provide a callback

```
function getDBPromise(): Promise<IDBDatabase|null> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = indexedDB.open("idb")
        request.onerror = (event) => {
            resolve(null)
        }
        request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
            resolve(null)
        }
        request.onsuccess = (event) => {
            resolve(request.result as IDBDatabase)
        }
        request.onblocked = () => {
            resolve(null)
        }
    })
}

async function awaitInAsyncFunction() {
    const IDB: IDBDatabase | null = await getDBPromise();
}


getDBPromise().then((db) => {
    const IDB: IDBDatabase | null = db;
})
```